# Wrong fetch of the primary key in laravel model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, primary-key

I am using PHP, Laravel 5 and MySQL. I am trying to fetch a Patient based on the authenticated user but I get a wrong value of the primary key.

In the PatientController I run this:

> $patient = Patient::where('userId', '=',
>   $request->user()->id)->get()->first();

The value of the patientId in the blade differs from the stored one.

for example, I get 3127

while the original value is 3127fc14-368e-4b06-90f2-a524986e627e

I don't face the same problem with the rest columns.

Thanks for your time and effort.

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function patient()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient', 'patientId','id');
    }
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $request['email'];
        $user->name = $request['name'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */

    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        if (Auth::attempt([ 'email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']] )){

            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**Patient.php**

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey='patientId';
    public $incrementing = 'false';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'patientId','contactId','guardianId','userId','patientNationalId','patientFirstName','patientSurName','patientDob','patientInsuranceNumber','patientGender'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','userId');
    }
}
```

**PatientController.php**

```
class PatientController extends Controller
{
    public function getDashboard(Request $request)
    {
        $patient = Patient::where('userId', '=', $request->user()->id)->get()->first();
        return view('dashboard', [
            'patient' => $patient
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Migrations**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password', 60);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('patients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('patientId')->primary();
    $table->string('contactId')->index()->nullable();
    $table->string('guardianId')->index()->nullable();
    $table->integer('userId')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->string('patientNationalId')->nullable();
    $table->string('patientFirstName')->nullable();
    $table->string('patientSurName')->nullable();
    $table->string('patientDob')->nullable();
    $table->string('patientGender')->nullable();
    $table->string('patientInsuranceNumber')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    # Foreign Keys
    $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('guardianId')->references('guardianId')->on('guardians');
    $table->foreign('contactId')->references('contactId')->on('contacts');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have userId as a foreign key that references id in users which is an integer.
When you say the original value is `3127fc14-368e-4b06-90f2-a524986e627e`, how do you create that `id`?

Your schema describes the type for the column to be an integer so 3127fc14-368e-4b06-90f2-a524986e627e will only result in an `integer` value of 3127

Comment: I am printing patientId, which is type string. What you say make sense, but I can't find the error...if I type {{ $patient }} in the blade I get the following json:


`{
"patientId":3127,
"contactId":
"0da44870-2b6a-11e6-9717-d70507957d0d",
"guardianId":"be3d1ad0-2b67-11e6-9f83-5d955f25c5f6",
"userId":2,
"patientNationalId":"968359452532"
,...}`